# Android pipeline modularization

Tags: android, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is it possible to build android modules separately and attach them in the main app artifact?

To contextualize:

> I need to decrease my build time in some pipeline and my application
> already is modularized. I would like to know if: theres a way to
> validate the only android module that has changes, build it and attach
> to my main application artifact (I don't know if this info is useful
> but I'm using Azure devops). For example let's use this imaginary
> application:

It consists in 3 modules: :app, :core, :domain.

> I changed only the core module, improving the database or wathever, I
> would like to build only the core module and attach it to the app or
> replace the core module already attached to the app (with app I mean
> apk or aab artifact that are already published as an artifact in Azure
> Devops).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Android builds, but if there aren't tightly coupled dependencies you create three individual builds, one for each module, and then put it all together for the release.  This would only work if each module can be built separately.

For example if you're using Git in Azure DevOps, depending on what your repos look like you could enable continuous integration on your three new builds and include a path filter with a path specification for the distinct paths.

Your could modify your release to pull artifacts from all three builds for your release.